# select custom id from same names using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table that contains fields for ID, Name and Color. I have a list of names in a windows form `ListBox` and I want that when I select each of them, it returns the selected item id from the database. To do that I used this code:

```
    public int GetIdByName(string name)
    {
        return MyTable.Where(c => c.Name == name).Select(c => c.ID).First();
    }
```

But it can only return the first id for similar names.mean when there are many similar name in table, it only return first id from first name.
how can fix this problem?

Comment: Your ListBox can hold actual objects - not just strings.  So that when they pick a row you already know the Id or color without hitting the database again.

Comment: Remove the First().

Comment: if I remove First(), i receive this error: 

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<int>' to 'int'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
I got All Id to List and in listBox_SelectedIndexChanged Event i got each selectedItem id.

```
    public List<int> GetAllID()
    {
        return MyTable.Select(c => c.ID).ToList();
    }     

    private void listBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var idList = db.MyTable.GetAllID();
        int id = idList[listBox.SelectedIndex];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<int> GetIdByName(string name)
{
    return MyTable.Where(c => c.Name == name).Select(c => c.ID).ToList();
}
```